# Radio button que al seleccionar uno, automáticamente vaya sumando hasta dar la nota final

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

tengo un cuadro, en ese cuadro está la descripción con sus notas cada vez que yo seleccione un radio button, este se encuentre en total y a lo ultimo de su nota final tengo el html, el cuadro y un poco de jQuery.

Este es un programa para dar su nota y su criterio de evaluación que el selector sea automático junto a la nota final suma de todos los input con sus radio button.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("input[type='radio']").on('change', function() {
                $("#rInput2").val($("input:radio[name=radio]:checked").val());
                sumar();


            });
        </script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cuadro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <section class="uno">

        <table width="974.0008999999999" height="372.667" border="3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th width="429.333" height="48.6667" scope="col" class="letra1">&nbsp;Aspectos de evaluación</th>
                    <th width="100" scope="col" class="calificacion1">&nbsp;0,2</th>
                    <th width="75.3333" scope="col" class="calificacion2">&nbsp;0,3</th>
                    <th width="81.3333" scope="col" class="calificacion3">&nbsp;0,5</th>
                    <th width="77.3333" scope="col" class="calificacion4">&nbsp;0,7</th>
                    <th width="78.6667" scope="col" class="calificacion5">&nbsp;1,0</th>
                    <th width="106" scope="col" class="total">&nbsp;Total</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th height="46" scope="col">&nbsp;Señala claramente la idea central del tema y muestra las ideas de apoyo en cada párrafo.</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="input2" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="0,3"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="0,5"> </th>
                    <th scope="col"> <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput2" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th height="46" scope="col">&nbsp;Se expresa con sus propias palabras y puede conectar el lenguaje empleado por el autor, de manera adecuada</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="input3" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio6" value="0,3"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio7" value="0,5"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio8" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio9" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput3" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th height="53.3333" scope="col">&nbsp;Utiliza frases breves y párrafos organizados de no más de 11 líneas. Evita coloquialismos y palabras innecesarias. Además, sabe parafrasear las ideas del autor.</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="input4" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio11" value="0,3"> </th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio12" value="0,5"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio13" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio14" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput4" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <th height="52" scope="col">&nbsp;Contextualiza y trata la información de manera adecuada</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="input2" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="radio16" value="0,2"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="radio17" value="0,5"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="radio18" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="radio19" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput2" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th height="54" scope="col">&nbsp;El uso de la ortografía, la y puntuación y los conectores lógicos es evidente en la redacción del texto.</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="input2" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio21" value="0,3"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio22" value="0,5"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio23" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio24" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput2" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th height="28.6667" scope="col">&nbsp;Evaluacion total</th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col">
                        <div id="resultado4"><input id="Subtotal" type="text" disabled>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pero, que es lo que falla o no te funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que siempre cambias el valor del mismo campo, porque accedes por ID. Te recomiendo:

- Usar `$(this)` para obtener el radio que fue marcado, será cualquiera en la tabla, no solo el de una fila en específico
- Obtener la fila de la tabla a donde pertenece el radio: [.closest('tr')](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- Buscar el campo a actualizar, especificando el tipo [.find('input[type="text"]')](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
- Finalmente, asignar el valor [.val(nuevoValor)](https://api.jquery.com/val/), tomándolo desde el radio que disparó el evento

```js
$("input[type='radio']").on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).val());
    // sumar();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cuadro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <section class="uno">

        <table width="974.0008999999999" height="372.667" border="3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th width="429.333" height="48.6667" scope="col" class="letra1">&nbsp;Aspectos de evaluación</th>
                    <th width="100" scope="col" class="calificacion1">&nbsp;0,2</th>
                    <th width="75.3333" scope="col" class="calificacion2">&nbsp;0,3</th>
                    <th width="81.3333" scope="col" class="calificacion3">&nbsp;0,5</th>
                    <th width="77.3333" scope="col" class="calificacion4">&nbsp;0,7</th>
                    <th width="78.6667" scope="col" class="calificacion5">&nbsp;1,0</th>
                    <th width="106" scope="col" class="total">&nbsp;Total</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th height="46" scope="col">&nbsp;Señala claramente la idea central del tema y muestra las ideas de apoyo en cada párrafo.</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="input2" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="0,3"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" value="0,5"> </th>
                    <th scope="col"> <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput2" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th height="46" scope="col">&nbsp;Se expresa con sus propias palabras y puede conectar el lenguaje empleado por el autor, de manera adecuada</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="input3" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio6" value="0,3"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio7" value="0,5"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio8" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio9" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput3" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th height="53.3333" scope="col">&nbsp;Utiliza frases breves y párrafos organizados de no más de 11 líneas. Evita coloquialismos y palabras innecesarias. Además, sabe parafrasear las ideas del autor.</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="input4" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio11" value="0,3"> </th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio12" value="0,5"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio13" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio14" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput4" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <th height="52" scope="col">&nbsp;Contextualiza y trata la información de manera adecuada</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="input2" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="radio16" value="0,2"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="radio17" value="0,5"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="radio18" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio3" id="radio19" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput2" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th height="54" scope="col">&nbsp;El uso de la ortografía, la y puntuación y los conectores lógicos es evidente en la redacción del texto.</th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="input2" value="0,2" checked=""></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio21" value="0,3"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio22" value="0,5"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio23" value="0,7"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio24" value="1,0"></th>
                    <th scope="col"><input id="rInput2" type="text" placeholder="0,2" class="monto">

                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th height="28.6667" scope="col">&nbsp;Evaluacion total</th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col"> </th>
                    <th height="35.6667" scope="col">
                        <div id="resultado4"><input id="Subtotal" type="text" disabled>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias si me sirvió una parte pero a lo ultimo quiero que sume todos los input y me de la nota final ?

Comment: @TatianaRodriiguez, asigna una clase a esos campos y los recorres con [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) para hacer la suma.